# Java Application Search Filter Parsing

Tags: java

I'm working on a java application. One of the modules needs a search filter as input. The search filter will have name, value parameters. The program should be able to detect and parse the following patterns:

```
 1. ((Name='Shaina')&(ID='26'))

 2. (Name='Shaina')
```

I need to be able to parse the filters to get key value pairs like:
Name='Shaina'
ID='26'

I would be using these name-value pairs for some database queries and related processing.
I have started with java regular expressions but it looks complicated to me as the number of parameters is dynamic.

Can you please suggest an efficient way or point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: Would you like to filter the expression by name? I didnt undestand.

Comment: @bpedroso I have edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need also to detect the logical operators or just the key=value part?

Comment: @zerologiko Just the key=value part. Thanks

Comment: It may be worth for you to look at [LL Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case I would recommend removing braces and ', splitting on '&' and parsing key-value pairs.

Example code

```
str = str.replaceAll("[()']", "");
String[] elements = str.split("&");
for (String elem : elements) {
  String[] pair = elem.split("=");
  String key = pair[0];
  String value = pair[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For very basic parsing you can use a regexp like 
`([A-Z,a-z,0-9]+)='([A-Z,a-z,0-9]+)'`

Test and and improve :) your regex here: http://regexr.com/3fbak

In Java you can use a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and a [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), see  [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#pattern-and-matcher) by Lars Vogel.